# How do I make assignments to an array int (*&Test)[10]?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I am having problems understanding how to assign to the `Test` array as shown below:
`int (*&Test)[10] = Parray;` `Test` is a reference to a pointer to an array of ten ints.
The error I get is as follows:

> error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [10]'|.

I have done my research without understanding this completely. I'm reading C++ Primer 5th edition.

```
int main() {
  int arr[10];
  int n = 5;
  int *ptr1 = &n;
  int arr2[10];
  int *ptrs[10]; // ptrs is an array of ten pointers

  // Parray points to an array of ten ints
  int (*Parray)[10] = &arr;
  // arrRef refers to an array of ten ints
  int (&arrRef)[10] = arr2;

  // Test is a reference to a pointer to an array of ten ints.
  int (*&Test)[10] = Parray;

  // How can I assign to Test[0..1..2..etc]?
  // This is what I am trying to do:
  Test[0] = ptr1; // Error here

  return 0;
}
```

How can I assign to `Test[0]` etc.?

Comment: No Test is a reference to a pointer which points to an array of 10 ints.

Comment: ^ it is the same type as 'arr'. If you want an array of pointers, you need to use your 'ptrs' variable somewhere

Comment: `ptr1` is an uninitialized pointer, it's not clear what you hope to do with `ptr1` and `ptrs` here

Comment: You can't assign directly to `Test[n]`. The type of [`Test`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*%26Test%29%5B10%5D+) is reference-to-pointer-to-array-of-10-int. `Test[0] = ...` , equivalent to `*Test = `, is attempting to *assign* something to an `int[10]`, which the language does not support. It would be equivalent to `int ar[10]; ar = ...`. If this isn't what you're intending in the first place (a likely possibility) then you need to clarify what you *expectation* is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
(*Test)[0] = 3;
(*Test)[1] = 5;
```

etc.  Alternatively you can write `Test[0][0] = 3; Test[0][1] = 5;` however I think that is less clear.

`Test` is a reference to the same type as `Parray`. Dereferencing this gives an array of 10 int, which you can then use array syntax on.

Answer (score 2):

Use the followi ng expression statement

```
Test[0][0] = *ptr1;
```

The type of expression `Test[0]` is `int [10]`. So `Test[0][0]` will have type `int` and `*ptr1` has type `int` Of course ptr1 shall have a valid value that may be dereferenced.